# Bifurcating Validation Error Messages in .Net

Tags: asp.net, validation

In ASP.Net, how do I limit validation messages to only one?

**Rule: User must put in a number between 0 and 1000.**

*Current [undesired] Behavior:*

User types 1001: validator says "Please put in a non-negative number beneath 1000"
User types -1: validator says "Please put in a non-negative number beneath 1000"

**Desired Behavior:**

User types 1001: validator says "Please put in a number beneath 1000"
User types -1: validator says "Please put in a non-negative number"

In other words, how can I use two asp:RangeValidators whose disallowed values intersect but only turn on the desired one? I do not want to handle a ServerValidate event on the server.

*Is it doable without client-side code?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [**CompareValidator**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.comparevalidator.aspx) to checks whether the value is less than zero and a `RangeValidator` to check whether the value is between -2147483647 and 1000.

```
<asp:CompareValidator Id="IsNotNegativeValidator"
                      ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
                      ValueToCompare="-1"
                      Operator="GreaterThan"
                      Type="Integer"
                      Text="Please put in a non-negative number"
                      runat="server"/>

<asp:RangeValidator   Id="IsLessThanOneThousandValidator"
                      ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
                      MinimumValue="-2147483647"
                      MaximumValue="1000"
                      Type="Integer"
                      Text="Please put in a number beneath 1000"
                      runat="server"/>
```

(In this particular case, it does seem like a single `RangeValidator` with the message "Please enter a number between 0 and 1000" would result in less user frustration.)

Comment: Thanks- I thought asp:CompareValidator is used only to compare controls, I never knew of the ValueToCompare attribute.

Comment: Let's say the user enters a non-integer, thus triggering these two irrelevant messages in addition to a third validation message specifying that the user must enter an integer.

Comment: Good question about non-integers - I don't think there's a way to do it without a custom validator or regular expression validator. That's yet another good reason to create a single validator with one comprehensive message stating *all* the rules governing the value. I can't imagine a user having a hard time figuring out which part of "Please enter a number between 0 and 1000" they violated.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'desired' behaviour has the potential to be somewhat irritating:

- User enters 1001
- App tells user "Please put in a number beneath 1000"
- Fair enough, user thinks, and enters -1 (which you will agree *is* "a number beneath 1000")
- App then tells user "Please put in a non-negative number"
- Why didn't you mention that to start with!?, user thinks to themselves

What I'm asking is: What's wrong with the existing behaviour, whereby the user is told the *actual* rule?

Comment: Let's say user types in "AAA"?

I wish it to say "Please enter a number".<br/><br/> 

Right now it says (after implementing an asp:CompareValidator):<br/><br/> 

Price should be numeric<br/>
Price should be non-negative<br/>
Enter a smaller number<br/><br/>

because technically it fails three validations but only the top one has any relevance.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found to do this is to use the RegularExpressionValidator exclusively. You can validate anything with the appropriate regular expression.